# Does ssh use the ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I can ssh into this machine `ssh user@remote_machine.com` and it always works. However I discovered that `ssh-add -l` shows no key (I had to replace my laptop a month ago). Does it mean that the ssh tool doesn't use the ssh agent?

What is the agent used for then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh` by default will check for certain identity files, for example `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. However, you can specify alternative identity files with `-i`. See `man ssh` for details.

ssh-agent helps manage identity files:

From `man ssh-agent`:

```
Multiple identities may be stored in ssh-agent concurrently and ssh(1)
will automatically use them if present.
```

One benefit of using ssh-agent is that if your private key is password-protected (recommended), you can unlock it once when adding it to your ssh-agent and you won't need to re-enter the password every time you use it.

Other benefits include agent forwarding. See `man ssh` for details.